# Why are the values of my form getting lost in php when sending them to an includes folder?

Tags: php, forms, get, messaging, dm

I am creating a messaging system in my website. I have a GET variable that I retrieve from the URL which indicates which user the inputted message should be sent to. I store this variable (messagesTo = $_GET['id']) in a form (with the message body and the logged-in user's id) and once the message is clicked, theoretically the included page should be called and the message should be stored in a DB based on the form's data.

[URL w/ user's id inside of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acX0C.png)

[Form page (directMessages.php)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7chv.png)

Instead, it says I get an error with the $_GET['id']. I have an error check and the message in the URL says that there is no value for $_GET['id']. No message is being sent to the database.

[directMessages Included page (directMessages.inc.php)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3kDp.png)

[Functions page for direct (dmFunctions.inc.php)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiGXL.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score -1):

You're not outputting the hidden values in your form (directMessages.php), ie:

```
<input name="messagesTo" type="hidden" value="<?php $_GET['id'] ?>">
```

should be

```
<input name="messagesTo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
```

Basically you need to `echo` the value for it to be present in the HTML.